# Separate a list in OCaml

Tags: list, ocaml

So I have a list that I'm trying to separate into two lists, such that all the even indices from the original list make up the first list, and the odd indices make up the second list.  Here is my attempt at the solution, but It's not returning correctly:

```
let rec separate xs =
  match xs with
    [] -> [],[]
  | x::y::xs -> x::separate xs, y::separate xs
  | x::[] -> x:: separate [], separate [];;
```

Comment: "...it's not returning correctly" - this code doesn't even compile since `separate` needs type `'a list -> 'a list * 'a list`, yet you're trying to do `x :: separate xs`. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `separate` returns a pair of lists, while when you write `x::separate xs` you are assuming that it returns a list (to which you prepend `x`).
Also, in the case `x::[]`, you already know the result, no need to recursively call `separate`.

Which yields:

```
let rec separate xs =
    match xs with
  | x::y::tail ->
        let a,b = separate tail in
        x::a, y::b
  | x::[] -> [x],[]
  | [] -> [],[];;
```

(If you post more questions, please post your code on several lines instead of just one, and with indentations).

Answer (score 0):

Answering from the distant future, but this can be addressed by mapping the indices onto the list, then using that to determine which list to add them to in a left fold. Given the use of `List.fold_left` we achieve a tail-recursive solution.

Both lists then simply need to be reversed.

```ml
$ rlwrap ocaml
OCaml version 5.0.0
Enter #help;; for help.

# let l1, l2 =
    [1; 2; 4; 7; 8; 9]
    |> List.mapi (fun x i -> (x, i))
    |> List.fold_left 
         (fun (l1, l2) (i, x) -> 
            if i mod 2 = 0 then (x::l1, l2) 
            else (l1, x::l2)) 
         ([], [])
  in
  List.(rev l1, rev l2);;
- : int list * int list = ([1; 4; 8], [2; 7; 9])
```

If we wish to conduct the map and fold in parallel we can use sequences.

```
# let l1, l2 =
    [1; 2; 4; 7; 8; 9]
    |> List.to_seq
    |> Seq.mapi (fun x i -> (x, i))
    |> Seq.fold_left 
         (fun (l1, l2) (i, x) -> 
            if i mod 2 = 0 then (x::l1, l2) 
            else (l1, x::l2)) 
         ([], [])
  in
  List.(rev l1, rev l2);;
- : int list * int list = ([1; 4; 8], [2; 7; 9])
```